# C# networkstream.ReadAsync can't read data shorter than bufferLength - stops working in the last byte

Tags: c#, networking, buffer

I have the following code to receive files. Sometimes the code works. Some other it stops. My bufferArray size is 8 KB. When I want to receive a file with fileSize 18 KB, The following thing happens. First two receive loops work perfectly. Then, with the 2 KB that remain, one more receive loop happens with bytesRead being around 1000 bytes. And then It doesn't run at all. It doesn't read the last 1000 bytes. How can I fix this? The problem is it doesn't read data shorter than buffer length..

```
while (sizeReceived <= fileSize)
{
    if ((bytesRead = await streamNET.ReadAsync(bufferArray, 0, bufferArray.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(bufferArray, 0, bytesRead); // save file bytes                
 
        packetNumber++;
        sizeReceived += bytesRead;
 
        if (sizeReceived > (0.9 * fileSize))
            OutputText3.text = $" T3 : Received: {fileName}, packets = {packetNumber}, sizeReceived = {sizeReceived} bytes.";
 
 
        // Successfull receive scenario
        if (fileSize == sizeReceived)
        {
            // remove string from Request list.
            ObjectListNet.RemoveAll(x => x == fileName);
           
            // Send ACK to server.
            data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Success");
            streamNET.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            break;
 
        }

 
    }
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the file being sent is `fileSize` bytes? It sounds like `ReadAsync` is returning 0 after it has read 17KB, which is exactly what it should do at the end of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

```
await streamNET.ReadAsync(bufferArray, 0, bufferArray.Length)
```

This reads some number of bytes `<= bufferArray.Length` into `buffer`, and returns the number that it read.

The thing is, you're asking for `bufferArray.Length` every time this is called. Even if you've received the whole file except 1 byte, you'll try read `bufferArray.Length` bytes.

You probably want to read `Math.Min(bufferArray.Length, fileSize - sizeReceived)` bytes.